# How to visualize a 2D array of Vectors in Java

Tags: java, visualization, data-visualization, vectorization

I have a 2D array where each element is a fixed length vector. I'm using Java and need to visualize the 2D array in the form of a color matrix (as in Matlab). I want to visualize how the vectors in the 2D array change with time (example:visualized in a loop 0...100).

I need help on the following.

1. What is the best value to represent each element of the 2D array? (I've used the norm but I want to confirm whether this is standard estimate of the vector)
2. What is the best possible way to visualize the 2D array mentioned above? (I thought writing my own visualization using Swing. Is there any other methods available which would save time?)

Comment: "save time" = what you are familiar with

Comment: @GaborSch I need to do this in Java since I have to integrate my modules with another system. Matlab is the easiest to do it and it will same me time but will not solve my problem. I don't want to port Matlab to Java.

Answer (score 0):

What about int [ ] [ ] matrix = new int [ 100 ] [ 100 ] 
To visualize it you can simply print it:

`for (int i=0; i<rows; i++) {`
`for (int j=0;j<cols;j++) {`
`System.out.println( matrix[i][j]+" ");`
`}`
`System.out.println();`
`}`

Comment: I know how to initialize the code. But, it does not answer my question mentioned above.